# Access project assets of custom cordova plugin within ionic project

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

As a bare cordova project we are able to gain access to the assets directory of the project via `this.cordova.getActivity().getAssets()`.

Is this also possible in combination with ionic? If not, is there a possibilty to access the ionic assets from java?

**Update:** After implementing my ionic app, 
 it seems to be no problem accessing the projects assets with `this.cordova.getActivity().getAssets()` as in a regular android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Android, there is an Ionic plugin called [File Path](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/)...

while the `assets` path should be `file://android_asset`.

this should result in getting a handle, most likely ...

```
this.filePath.resolveNativePath("file://android_asset")
  .then(filePath => console.log(filePath))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

also see [Cordova Plugin File](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file), which it seems to abstract.

Comment: I'm sorry, does this mean I am able to access the ionic assets from a module with e.g. resolveNativePath("../assets", successCallback, errorCallback)?

Comment: Seems like a wasn't specific, I meant the assets directory within the project.

Comment: @Entertain you need to use a promise, updated the answer... and this obviously won't get the project's asset directory, which is located on your computer... but the one within the compiled APK package.